# How to fix "Attribute error" when using pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm writing a code that requires columns from a csv file to be turned into lists. This is the error I get, AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

I've tried changing all to name and names, but with no luck. It only changes the error message.

```
with open('The Project- 6-21 E on leg arc test 1.csv', "r") as csvfile:

    colnames = [ 'sensor', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'azimuth', 'elevation', 'roll', 'timestamp']

    data = pd.read_csv('The Project- 6-21 E on leg arc test 1.csv', names = colnames)

    names = data.name.tolist()

    x = data.x.tolist()
```

It should be creating a total of three lists (not all shown), but is currently getting hung up at name

Comment: If you're getting an error message, please include the full error traceback in your question, as that can help diagnose the issue. In this case, it doesn't appear that you've set the `.name` attribute of the dataframe, and you haven't passed in `'name'` as one of your column names, so what are you trying to refer to with `data.name`?

Comment: (As an aside, best practice is to access dataframe columns with `df['column']` rather than `df.column`, as it can help prevent some of these types of ambiguities)

Comment: `data.name` inside `names = data.name.tolist()` is not defined inside your `colnames`. If you comment that statement out, your `x = data.x.tolist()` should work?

Comment: @MigB it's also worth noting that dataframes have a `name` attribute which can _also_ be accessed by `df.name`, and it's unclear in this scenario what the original intent was

Comment: @G.Anderson The intend seems clear to be _columns from a csv file to be turned into lists_. Using the `tolist()`function seems to make sense with transferring a column.

Comment: @MigB I agree that this is the most likely interpretation, however I've definitely seen weirder misunderstandings of how things work in pandas than the alternative interpretation lol

Comment: @MigB  Thank you! I have no idea how pandas works. This is just what I found online when I was searching for help putting my data to lists. This worked perfectly. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use the `pd.read_csv()` function, you don't need to `open()` your .csv file before.

Another point is, that you try to call a not defined key (look for my comment).

```
import pandas as pd

colnames = [ 'sensor', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'azimuth', 'elevation', 'roll', 'timestamp']
data = pd.read_csv('The Project- 6-21 E on leg arc test 1.csv', names = colnames)

#names = data.name.tolist()
#^^^not working, because data.name (= date['name']) doesn't exist in your colnames

x = data.x.tolist()
```

Comment: Very good point about the built-in context manager for pandas `read_csv`